# Antiparticle solution of the Dirac Equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, antimatter, dirac-equation, charge-conjugation

I'm really confused by the antiparticle solution of the Dirac equation. I follow Chapter 11 of Schwartz's book "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model" and find a couple of problems.

In equation(11.17), it tells us that the solutions are:

$$u_s=\begin{pmatrix} \xi_s \\ \xi_s \end{pmatrix}, v_s=\begin{pmatrix} \eta_s \\ -\eta_s \end{pmatrix}$$

then it gives an example in (11.18):

$$
u_{\uparrow}= \sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, u_{\downarrow}= \sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},
v_{\uparrow}= \sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},
v_{\downarrow}= \sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}
$$

This seems to imply that:

$$
\xi_{\uparrow}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \xi_{\downarrow}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},
\eta_{\uparrow}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\eta_{\downarrow}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

The $\xi$ part makes sense to me because it's the same as what I learned in QM class. The $\eta$ part is really confusing to me. If I use the spin operator $S_z = \frac{\sigma^3}{2}$ on it, I get:

$$
S_z\eta_{\uparrow} = -\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\uparrow},
S_z\eta_{\downarrow} = -\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\downarrow}
$$

which seems to imply that both of them are spin down. Later in (11.43), it shows that charge conjugation indeed take $u_{\uparrow}$ (spin up particle) to $v_{\downarrow}$(spin down antiparticle), and $u_{\downarrow}$ (spin down particle) to $v_{\uparrow}$(spin up antiparticle).

I tried to look for answer from other books, which makes me more confused. In Peskin and Schroeder's book, bottom of page61, it says that $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ corresponds to spin $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ corresponds to spin $+\frac{1}{2}$, which is different from Schwartz's book and runs into problem when I take the charge conjugation.

Can anyone provide an answer that what is the correct form of $\eta_s$?

Comment: $S_z\eta_\uparrow = \frac{1}{2} \eta_\uparrow$. The minus sign of the first component doesn't matter, because the eigenvalue equation is also valid for $-\eta_\uparrow$.